# How to Programmatically Pre-select Cells in a Multi-select UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multi-select

I use a `UITableView` to let the user select from a number of given options with multiple selections allowed. I also want the user to later return to this view and change a previously made selection, which means that I must be able to load and initialize the table with the earlier selections. Furthermore, the user can tap a "select-all" button, which should programmatically set all options.

To do this, I have an array of booleans that keeps track of checked and unchecked items. However, in order to correctly trigger `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` events, the table view also needs to be aware of the selection status. So I came up with two options, neither of which I'm entirely happy with:

**Setting the cell accessory types using my own array:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = items[indexPath.row].name
    if items[indexPath.row].isSelected {
        cell!.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell!.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .checkmark
    ...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .none
    ...
}
```

This nicely toggles the states and updates the backing array. What it fails to do is keeping the table view aware of the selection state of each cell. So it happens that, on reload, the wrong selection event (did select/did deselect) is triggered and then requires the user to initially tap twice for changing the state. Now I could work around this by handling both statuses in both `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` but it contradicts the status of the control and may later lead to problems.

**Letting the table view keep track of the state:**

Here, I replaced

```
if isSelected(index: indexPath.row) {
```

with

```
if let selectedRows = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
```

This keeps the table view internally updated but I have not found a good way to programmatically set the state when the user returns to the table with some pre-selected items or when "select-all" is clicked. Trying to iterate through my array and setting the selections using e.g.

```
`tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)`
```

(as suggested in answers to similar questions) where applicable did not lead to the desired result.

What would be the best way to initialize my table with pre-selected values and update it when "select-all" is clicked?

Comment: Are you updating the items[indexPath.row].isSelected property on the cell click ?

Comment: @RTXGamer Yes, that part is working. I left this out from the code I posted to focus on the actual problem, which is how to best keep track of the selection state.

Comment: As you've updated the data model too, it shouldn't be a problem now to keep track of the cell selection status. You though have to loop through and update isSelected for SelectAll feature now.

Comment: Yes, I guess I was aiming to take advantage of the multi-select properties of the table view, and there the issue was not so much keeping track of the status as initially setting it from the data model (sorry, I was not very precise in my last comment). But, I agree: there is no need to replicate the status tracking. Seems like I needed someone to reaffirm me on something that should have been obvious as it is pretty much option 1 in the question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should manage it entirely using your data model.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    // Assumption: item is a class, so changes are reflected in array as expected
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    item.isSelected.toggle()

    cell!.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
}
```

This way there's always one source of truth, your data model. Your tableView instance should not need to remember anything for you, it's driven by the data you provide.

If you go this way, you don't need to implement `didDeselect` delegate method OR set `allowsMultipleSelection` to `true`.

Comment: Thank you. I like this because it is simpler and it does not even pretend to let the table handle multiple selections.

Comment: I would consider not using `isSelected` at all, if another name is more suitable, like `isChecked`. to insure it's not affected by tableView